# How can I exclude the admin area from the litespeed cache when running Magento?

Tags: magento, litespeed

I have litespeed on my server and am trying to use the cache system.  I have followed [the wiki instructions](http://www.litespeedtech.com/support/wiki/doku.php?id=litespeed_wiki:litespeed:cache:magento&s=magento).

And have this in my Magento `.htaccess`

```
RewriteRule (.*\.php)?$ - [L,E=Cache-Control:max-age=120]
```

The cache is working as I'm getting the `X-response` hit in the header but I can't find a way to exclude the admin area from the cache.

Comment: Could you clarify whether the question is about getting the cache to work or excluding the admin area from the cache?

Comment: @Ladadadada , sorry for delay in replying ... Yes the cache is working but can't exclued admin area ...?

Answer (score 0):

Add these lines before your RewriteRule:

RewriteCond %{ORG_REQ_URI} !^/admin/
RewriteCond %{ORG_REQ_URI} !^/admin$
RewriteCond %{ORG_REQ_URI} !^/index.php/admin/
RewriteCond %{ORG_REQ_URI} !^/index.php/admin$